# Find My Mac - WPS and Proxies

Tags: find-my-mac

Is it possible to trick the Wi-Fi Positioning Service using proxies? My Mac got stolen a couple of days ago in Rome Italy and located in Algerie today.

Answer (score 2):

Find my Mac checks all available WiFis in the local area and compares them to a huge database, but also with a proxy, vpn or similar, the mac still gets the signals of the local wifi and not of the final access point, so no, you probably can't trick this service by that way.

I'm very sorry for you.